# Usage of printf command in vim

Tags: vimrc

I see from `:h printf` that there's a print function in vim:

> `printf({fmt}, {expr1} ...)`      printf()
>                   Return a String with {fmt}, where "%" items are replaced by
>                   the formatted form of their respective arguments.  Example:
>                           printf("%4d: E%d %.30s", lnum, errno, msg)

However, when I try doing something basic like:

```
:printf('Hello, %s', 'name')
```

I get the following error:

> E492: Not an editor command: printf('Hello, %s', 'name')

What would be the correct usage, if any, of the `printf` command, and where can it be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf()` is a *function*, not a *command*. And in Vim everything must start with a command.

So while calling a function either put it on rhs, or use `:call` command (when you don't care for return value).

But note that `printf()` is analog to `sprintf()` in C, so `:call printf(...)` doesn't make any sense. So you must do

```
:echo printf('Hello, %s', 'name')
```